# SQLAlchemy is not creating certain columns

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, self-reference

I'm trying to set up a self-referential many-to-many database via an association object (since I need to add a value in the relationship).

I have searched all over Stack Exchange, Google and the SQLAlchemy documentation, but I haven't found a single similar instance.

The model definitions are (Python3.8):

```py
class Recipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    base_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('color.id'))
    ingredients = db.relationship('Color',
            backref='recipe',
            cascade='save-update')
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, ingredient, quantity):
        print(f'{ingredient=}\n{quantity=}')
        self.ingredients = ingredient
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Recipe({self.ingredients} x{self.quantity})'

class Color(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    medium = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    pure = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    _recipe = db.relationship(Recipe,
            primaryjoin=id==Recipe.base_id,
            join_depth=1)
    recipe = association_proxy('_recipe', 'ingredients',
        creator = lambda _: _)
    swatch = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, medium, name, pure, *, recipe=None, swatch):
        self.medium = medium.upper()
        self.name = name
        self.pure = pure
        self.swatch = swatch

        if self.pure:
            self.recipe = [Recipe(self, 1)]
        else:
            for ingredient, quantity in recipe:
                self.recipe.append(Recipe(ingredient, quantity))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Color({self.name})'
```

I am using a SQLite database.

I would expect to have a column for each attribute in both tables, but for some reason, this is the only table creation SQL generated:

```
CREATE TABLE color (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        medium VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        pure BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
        swatch VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE (name),
        CHECK (pure IN (0, 1)),
        UNIQUE (swatch)
)

CREATE TABLE recipe (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        base_id INTEGER,
        quantity INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        FOREIGN KEY(base_id) REFERENCES color (id)
)
```

I am receiving no errors.  If I use the cli to manually input records, all defined columns save, though not entirely correctly.  I think that may be due to the missing columns, though, and will post it as a separate issue if needed, later.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would expect to have a column for each attribute in both tables"?

Comment: @IljaEverilä as is, the database has no "color.recipe" or "recipe.ingredients" columns. It also doesn't maintain referential integrity to these attributes upon closing and reopening

Comment: Those are an `association_proxy` and a `relationship` respectively, which handle the **object** side of the Object Relational Mapping, so they're not supposed to show up in your database. As to referential integrity not being maintained, please show a [mcve], and remember that SQLite *does not* enforce foreign key constraints by default, but instead it has to be enabled on a per connection basis.

Comment: @IljaEveril&#228; Hmm. I have apparently not understood relationship and association_proxy very well. So they don&#39;t create columns? How would I put the data they contain into a column, then? And the referential integrity issue is apparently caused by this.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ok. If association_proxy and relationship don't create columns, how do I put their contained data into the database? I'm confused.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I did enable SQLite foreign keys in __init__.py I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Maybe I went about it all wrong, but what I am trying to accomplish is after querying from the database: `if Color(blurg).pure: Color(blurg).recipe = [(Color(blurg), quantity=1)] else: Color(blurg).recipe = [(Color(regray), quantity=2), (Color(dfg), quantity=5)]`